# With imminent surgery scheduled, should I postpone applying to junior developer jobs?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, junior

I'm going to apply to junior Backend .NET Web Developer jobs soon, but I'm not sure if this is an appropriate time to apply, given my obligations in the next few months.

I have a major teeth extractions surgery scheduled for July 23, five teeth in total. It's about 2 months from now. And the doctor stated that it will take about 1 or 2 weeks for complete recovery, unless there are any complications.

My question is, given my situation, is it prudent to apply to the web developer jobs right now? I'm asking because I don't want to start working and end up taking off 2 weeks from work, only 2 months or so after starting the new job. This will most likely be a 100% remote position although it could also end up being partly remote/onsite, or 100% onsite.

Comment: It is a non-issue, apply now and enjoy.

Comment: " I'm anticipating that it will take about 1 or 2 weeks to recover from the oral surgery, not to mention any complication that may arise." - you get that done in some jungle without any modern medicine? My last tooth extraction had a downtime of 2 days. Also - you should not "anticipate", you should ask your doctor. This is a standard procedure.

Comment: @TomTom I made the corrections to my post. Thanks.

Comment: You should apply now obviously, however, the elephant in the room is you won’t have earned the leave for 2 weeks (honestly 2 weeks is the average for the private sector).  Now this should not be a problem, if you need the surgery, you need the surgery. 2 week recovery for mouth surgery seems extremely long.

Comment: "1 or 2 weeks for complete recovery" doesn't necessarily mean you will need to be off work for 2 weeks? Talk to your dentist but it's more likely that they mean you'll have some pain etc for 2 weeks before you're fully normal, but I'd expect to be able to go back to work after a couple of days? (Schedule the surgery for a Friday and that will take care of 2 of the days...)

Comment: @seventyeightist Good suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Note that in some countries like the UK routine extraction of non-symptomatic wisdom teeth is much less common. Only if they cause pain is a dentist visit recommended (compare https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/wisdom-tooth-removal/ with https://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/wisdom-tooth-extraction/about/pac-20395268)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Apply now**

Hiring takes time. Getting an interview takes time. In plenty of companies, such as mine, taking two weeks off right at the start for a medical concern would not be a problem anyway.

Comment: Ok. I'm going to apply now. Thanks everyone!

Comment: This is a great answer. I just wanted to suggest being upfront about your planned absence in the late stages of the process, when discussing your job offer and starting date: as Matthew mentioned, it's unlikely to be a concern, but giving the hiring manager and the HR a heads up would be the right thing to do.

Comment: @Egor I'll consider doing this. Thanks.